# Replace Value in Custom format for MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a set of data for example:
Part no        Custom Format
1128005        \Machines\3D\PartNo(2)\PartNo(4)xx\PartNo(7)
11.88.006     \Machines\3D\PartNo(2)\PartNo+3(2)xx\PartNo+6(3)

I want to replace the variable set in the custom format define in it. The result i am looking for is 
For Part no
1128005 
the result is
\Machines\3D\11\1128xx\1128005

11.88.006 
\Machines\3D\11\88xx\006

Any ideas?

Thanks
Regards

Comment: do it at the client. Really.

Comment: sorry, i don get the idea to do it at the client. The Table contain 7 million rows of data.

Comment: But you won't send all 7 million to the client. Even if you did, client will be better at than the database.

Comment: actually i am doing an IS migration. Cause the structure of the database from my current system does things differently and storing the data differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, below script should be what you want? But because it processes row by row, it can be very slow when dealing with millions of rows.

```
--declare @input varchar(50) = '11.88.006', @pattern varchar(255) = '\Machines\3D\PartNo(2)\PartNo+3(2)xx\PartNo+6(3)'
declare @input varchar(50) = '1128005', @pattern varchar(255) = '\Machines\3D\PartNo(2)\PartNo(4)xx\PartNo(7)'
declare @tblPattern table (tmpKey int identity(1,1), result varchar(50), Position varchar(50), SkipCnt int, CharLength int, Sufix varchar(50))
declare @i int = 1, @output varchar(max) = '\Machines\3D\'

Declare @PatternXml XML
Set @PatternXml = N'<root><r>' + REPLACE(replace(@pattern, '\Machines\3D\', ''), '\', '</r><r>') + '</r></root>'

insert into @tblPattern(result)
select r.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as t
from @PatternXml.nodes('//root//r') as records(r)

update @tblPattern set Position = REPLACE(result, 'PartNo', '')
    , SkipCnt = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('+', result, 1) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(result, CHARINDEX('+', result, 1)  + 1, CHARINDEX('(', result, 1) - CHARINDEX('+', result, 1)  - 1) ELSE 0 END
    , CharLength = SUBSTRING(result, CHARINDEX('(', result, 1) + 1,  CHARINDEX(')', result, 1) - CHARINDEX('(', result, 1) - 1 )
    , Sufix = SUBSTRING(result, CHARINDEX(')', result, 1) + 1, LEN(result))

while @i <= 3
begin

    select @output += SUBSTRING(@input, 1 + SkipCnt, CharLength) + Sufix + '\'
    from @tblPattern 
    where tmpKey = @i

    set @i += 1

end

select @output = STUFF(@output, len(@output), 1, '')
select @output
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working!! 1 more question. What if i would like to contain the \Machine\3D path? It is too changing from each part no.

Comment: As you can see I removed "\machines\3D\" part when load value into table variable, so to treat this part as dynamic part as well, I would create an extra column in the table variable to store this part, and then transform it by business rules.

Comment: Thanks. i got it. Sorry as my SQL skill isn't that good. But how do i implement it over the whole records?

Comment: Just from "get the job done" perspective, I would create a user defined function and then update the data set. But as I said, for each row this approach will create a small table variable and process the string transformation. Seriously it can be very slow. So you need to grab a portion and do your own test.

Comment: Hi, i got it working for user define function. I have encounter 1 more custom format type which is \Machines\3D\PartNo(2)\PartNo+3(2)xx\PartNo+6(3)_PartNo(2)

Comment: The formatting type essentially follows the same rule as other format types. The PartNo(2) is just a part of suffix so you can simple change the code a little bit to handle this format.